# Pass an entire yaml from values to templates without filling empty fields with nulls

Tags: go, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, open-telemetry

I am trying to pass given part of values.yaml into helm template:

```
  receivers:
    test1:
      test2:
        test3:
    test4:
```

using function:

`{{ .Values.receivers | toYaml | nindent 2}}`

Code is placed in correct format, however empty fields get filled with 'null':

```
receivers:
  test1:
    test2:
      test3: null
  test4: null
```

Is there any way to prevent this?

I am expecting correct templating without insterted null fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no fields inserted. The processor only replaces values that already exist with a different serialization that has the same semantics.

`test3:` in YAML without a value is parsed as having an empty scalar value. The [YAML Core Schema](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#103-core-schema) defines the following for empty values:

| Regular expression | Resolved to tag |
| --- | --- |
| `null | Null | NULL | ~` | tag:yaml.org,2002:null |
| *`/* Empty */`* | tag:yaml.org,2002:null |

Since the empty value is resolved to have the tag `!!null` (which is a shorthand for the full form shown above), it is loaded as **`nil`** into Go.

When `toYaml` receives your data, it doesn't know that the **`nil`** values originated from empty scalars. It needs to choose one of the possible serializations and chooses `null`. This adheres to the YAML spec and is therefore correct behavior.

Any downstream processor that supports the Core Schema should process `test3: null` in the same way it processes `test3:` without value. Therefore there should be no problem.

If you want `test3:` to specifically have the *empty string* as value instead of `null`, write

```yaml
test3: ""
```

If you want it to contain an empty mapping, write

```yaml
test3: {}
```